# Workflow stuck in 'Starting' status - MOSS 2007

Tags: 2007, workflow, visual-studio

Maybe someone can help me debug this

I've created a simple sequential workflow in VS2008 on server 2003(64 bit) and wspbuilder workflow feature tempalte.

When I trigger the workflow manually it works fine everytime.

However when I set the workflow to trigger on new item created it gets stuck in the 'Starting' status.

Things I've checked:

i)   Workflow History list is not updated 
ii)  Timer Service is running. 
iii) The site has an SSP 
iv)  Breakpoints are not hit when the w3wp process is attached.

Help any ideas ??

At this stage I've stripped the workflow down to just posting a couple of messages to the ULS log (it does almost nothing).

Comment: More information comes to light when I run the workflow agains a different webapplication on the same farm the workflow completes with no problem. Both web applications are using the same appPool. 

I guess that means its got to be related to the web application the workflow is/(is not) running in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that might help narrow down the problem would be to try attaching one of the out-of-the-box workflows to your list/library.

If that works as expected, then it would indicate an issue with your specific workflow code.

If the OOB workflow also gets stuck in starting, then it would indicate more of an issue with your SharePoint farm setup.

Comment: Hey Paul, 

Thanks for the idea, I did try and out of the box approval workflow on the list and it is also stuck in the 'starting' status. The frustrating this is that I don't even hit the initialization event of my custom workflow making it quite hard to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

If your workflow running in document library.Its may be 'stuck' because of document is check-out.To avoid this situation : 
Try create a loop .First check document is check out or not.If document is chekcout.
Stop your thread 10 second

Int16 Counter = 0;
            while (Counter <= 4)
            {
                try
                {
                    workflowProperties.Item.Properties["Submitted For Review"] = "Yes";
                    workflowProperties.Item.SystemUpdate();
                    Counter = 8;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
                    Counter++;
                }
            }

Comment: If this is the case - you should be able to check if the document is checked out by checking if the SPListItem.File.Level is SPFileLevel.Checkout. E.g. if (workflowProperties.Item.File.Level == SPFileLevel.Checkout)
{
// File is checked out
}

Hope this helps!